# Ensure CORS response header values are valid error with AWS Amplify, ELB and EC2 backend nginx

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

I have a React frontend that is deployed on AWS Amplify. (let's say its URL is `https://master.foo.amplifyapp.com`)

And I have an EC2 backend instance that runs docker containers which are nginx and REST API nodejs server(Koa).

Also, I've set up ELB to accept only HTTPS access. (let's say its URL is `https://example.com/`)

So the request flow looks something like this.

```
Amplify(https://master.foo.amplifyapp.com) -- API request --> https://example.com/api/**/** --> ELB --> EC2 --> nginx --> http://docker-backend:3000 --> EC2
```

I had no issue with it most of the time however it returns CORS error for a specific request.

Here are the details of the Request/Response headers:

1. Request which WORKS:

```
General
  Request URL: https://example.com/api/aaa/bbb
  Request Method: OPTIONS
  Status Code: 204 
  Remote Address: XX.XX.XXX.XXX:443
  Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers
  access-control-allow-headers: access-control-allow-origin,content-type
  access-control-allow-methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH
  access-control-allow-origin: https://master.foo.amplifyapp.com
  date: Wed, 22 Sep 2021 21:42:25 GMT
  server: nginx/1.21.3
  vary: Origin

Request Headers
  :authority: example.com
  :method: OPTIONS
  :path: /api/aaa/bbb
  :scheme: https
  accept: */*
  accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, be
  accept-language: ja,en;q=0.9
  access-control-request-headers: access-control-allow-origin,content-type
  access-control-request-method: POST
  origin: https://master.foo.amplifyapp.com
  referer: https://master.foo.amplifyapp.com/
  sec-fetch-dest: empty
  sec-fetch-mode: cors
  sec-fetch-site: cross-site
  user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.45
```

2. Request which does NOT WORK:

```
General
  Request URL: https://example.com/api/ccc/ddd
  Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers
  content-length: 534
  content-type: text/html
  date: Wed, 22 Sep 2021 21:50:13 GMT
  server: awselb/2.0

Request Headers
  :authority: example.com
  :method: POST
  :path: /api/ccc/ddd
  :scheme: https
  accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
  accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
  accept-language: ja,en;q=0.9
  access-control-allow-origin: *
  content-length: 11707
  content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
  origin: https://master.foo.amplifyapp.com
  referer: https://master.foo.amplifyapp.com/
  sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"
  sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
  sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
  sec-fetch-dest: empty
  sec-fetch-mode: cors
  sec-fetch-site: cross-site
  user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36
```

Plus here is my `nginx.conf`

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  8000;
}

http {
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile            on;
  tcp_nopush          on;
  tcp_nodelay         on;
  keepalive_timeout   65;
  types_hash_max_size 4096;

  include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type        application/octet-stream;

  # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
  # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
  # for more information.

  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
      try_files $uri /index.html;
      gzip_static on;
      charset UTF-8;
      charset_types text/css;
    }

    location /api/ {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_pass http:/docker-backend/:3000/;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, here is the short version of my Koa setting:

```js
import Koa, { Middleware } from 'koa'
import cors from '@koa/cors'

const app = new Koa()
app.use(cors())
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('koa is listening on port 300....'))
```

Lastly, here is the error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/api/ccc/ddd' from origin 'https://master.foo.amplifyapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I couldn't understand why some requests would fail with CORS and others would not, even though we were using the same backend API server.

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Looks like the failing request is not even hitting nginx as the `server` header is the ELB. Is the ELB blocking `POST` requests? Also, nginx is listening on port 80, so are you terminating SSL at the ELB?

Comment: I thought ELB blocking `POST` requests too but I guess that's not it since other `POST` requests went through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer by looking at the log.
My `POST` request became `OPTION` since it's json data format and it caused `CORS preflight` and then the response state became pending.

Then, the nginx log from docker showed an error `upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)` since the task which always fails by CORS was pretty heavy task so that it took more than 60 seconds to get the response from the server.

So I removed `keepalive_timeout 65;` and added `proxy_read_timeout 3600;` and it worked ;)

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html